# Setting table width to minimum

Tags: html

I was wondering how can I change the table's width to minimum using HTML such that the TABLE displays as

> N 
>  A 
>  M 
>  E 
>  
>  N 
>  A 
>  M 
>  E 
>  H 
>  E
>
>  R 
>  E

This is the code

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table style="word-wrap: anywhere; max-width: 1px">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add spaces between each character it will work.

```html
<table width="1px">
<tr>
<th>N a m e</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>N a m e  h e r e</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with in-line css at the table, or just a `style` at the start of the html. Having a css file would be much better tho. Just type `width: (value)` and put into the 'value' the one you want, you can try `min-width` or just 1px. Also what the friend above said.